# Passing a value from one form to another form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have two forms named `form1` and `form2`:

- `form1` is made of a `label` and a `button`.
- `form2` is made of a `textBox` and a `button`

When I click the `form1` button, this will show up `form2`. Any inputs in `textBox` should be written back to `form1.label` once I hit the button in `form2`.
I have the code below but it doesn't work.

```
// Code from Form 1
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public void PassValue(string strValue)
    {
        label1.Text = strValue;
    }
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 objForm2 = new Form2();
        objForm2.Show();
    }

}

// Code From Form 2

public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 objForm1 = new Form1();
        objForm1.PassValue(textBox1.Text);
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

And a screenshot:

[image: Application screenshot]

How can I realize that?

Comment: you can pass the instance of Form1 into the constructor of Form2 and store it as an attribute in Form2

Comment: I've listed exactly that solution.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You don't access your form1, from which you created form2. In form2 button1_Click you create new instance of Form1, which is not the same as initial. You may pass your form1 instance to form2 constructor like that:

```
   // Code from Form 1
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public void PassValue(string strValue)
    {
        label1.Text = strValue;
    }
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 objForm2 = new Form2(this);
        objForm2.Show();
    }

}

// Code From Form 2

public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    Form1 ownerForm = null;

    public Form2(Form1 ownerForm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.ownerForm = ownerForm;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {       
        this.ownerForm.PassValue(textBox1.Text);
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I was trying to return data from one form to another form in C# since morning, almost tried dozens of code example but was not working, with your this example I am now able to achieve what I was looking but my OOP concept is not clear and I am trying to understand constructor. I am new to OOP and learning C# and getting a hard time understanding things. : (

Answer (score 5):

Like mentioned in other posts, you won't be able to reference the original Form1 by creating a new instance of Form1.  You can pass Form1 into Form2's constructor or expose Form2's text as a public property, but I usually prefer using delegates for this to maintain loose coupling.

```
// Code from Form 1
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 objForm2 = new Form2();
        objForm2.PassValue += new PassValueHandler(objForm2_PassValue);
        objForm2.Show();
    }
    public void objForm2_PassValue(string strValue)
    {
        label1.Text = strValue;
    }
}

// Code From Form 2
public delegate void PassValueHandler(string strValue);
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public event PassValueHandler PassValue;

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (PassValue != null)
        {
            PassValue(textBox1.Text);
        }
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Delegates are much more preferred. Nice code. Work as a charm. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

When you are doing:

```
Form1 objForm1 = new Form1();
objForm1.PassValue(textBox1.Text);
```

... you are creating a new `Form1` and calling the `PassValue` method on the wrong `Form1` object. Instead, you could do:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    // This is the text that will be entered in form2
    public String form2text;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Show form2
        Form2 objForm2 = new Form2(this);
        objForm2.ShowDialog();
        // When form2 is closed, update the label text on form1
        label1.Text = form2text;
    }
}

public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    // This is the instance of Form1 that called form2
    private Form1 form1caller;

    public Form2(Form1 form1caller)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.form1caller = form1caller;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Pass the textBox value to form1 before closing form2
        form1caller.form2text = textBox1.Text;
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I just tried this code and it works, sure it will help you.

**in the first form (`Form1`) type below:**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 f = new Form2(textBox1.Text);
        f.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

**in the second form (`Form2`) use below codes:**

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2( string st)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        textBox1.Text = st;
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
class Form2
{
    public string ReturnedText = "";

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ReturnedText = textbox1.Text;
        Close();
    }
}
```

and in form1

```
Form2 objForm2 = new Form2();
objForm2.ShowDialog();
string ret = objForm2.ReturnedText;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass reference on form1 to form2 instead of creating new instance in this code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1 objForm1 = new Form1(); // ← this is another form1, not that you see
    objForm1.PassValue(textBox1.Text);
    this.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are going to do:

```
// Code from Form 1
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public string MyValue { get; set; }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 objForm2 = new Form2();
        objForm2.textBox1.Text = MyValue;
        objForm2.MainForm = this;
        objForm2.Show();
    }
}

// Code From Form 2

public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form1 MainForm { get; set; }
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MainForm.MyValue = textBox1.Text;
        MainForm.Show();
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: But where is there objForm1 declaration in Form2 class?

Comment: `public Form MainForm` - used the `Form` base class where Form2 is derived from `Form`. The usage can be availed with `Form` class

Comment: Thank you for the help, but i got this error "name 'objForm1' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: I'm so sorry - I have just updated the code, please `Form2` class. This should work

Answer (score 0):

The way that I normally approach this requirement is as follows:

I place a public property on the Form2 class:

```
public string ValueFromForm1 { get; set; }

//In the constructor, or other relevant method, I use the value
public Form2()
{
  form2LabelToDisplayForm1Value.Text = ValueFromForm1;
}
```

In order to return something to Form1, you need to add a public property to the Form1 class to receive the value, and then send a reference to the form to Form2, so that Form2 can set the value:

```
//Add reference property to Form2 class
public Form1 CallingForm { get; set; }

//Form2 can access the value on Form1 as follows:
private someMethod()
{
  this.CallingForm.ValueFromForm2 = "Info coming from form 2";
}
```

then

```
//Add public property to Form1 class
public string ValueFromForm2 { get; set; }

//When Form2 is created, set the reference property
Form2 objForm2 = new Form2();
objForm2.CallingForm = this;
objForm2.Show();
```

Since Form2 now has a reference to the Form1 that created, there is no need to call new Form1() anywhere in Form2. All Form2 has to do is set the value on the reference, and then close itself.

Answer (score 0):

Form 1 code...:-

```
namespace Passing_values_from_one_form_to_other    
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string str;
        private String value1;//taking values from form no _of_test_cases

        public string value
        {
            get { return value1; }
            set { value1 = value; }
        }


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            textBox1.Text = str;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 f2 = new Form2();
            f2.ShowDialog();
            str = f2.passvalue;
        }
    }
}
```

Form 2 code....:-

```
namespace Passing_values_from_one_form_to_other
{

 public partial class Form2 : Form

    {
         private string str;
        public string passvalue
        {
            get { return  str; }
            set { str = value; }
        }

        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Btn_Ok1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            passvalue = textBox1.Text;
            this.Close();

        }
    }
}
```

directly execute it u will get the clear picture....same way u can pass values from one form to other...

post your comments if you face any issues...

hope this will help...

or else you can refer this video...

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PI3ad-TebP0