# Passing data to previous window form from another window form

Tags: c#, database, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I'm working on a windows form application in visual studio 2010. I'm trying to refresh and add new learning on my knowledge on C# and querying a database.

details: [I am not working on an MDI form but with several windforms and a local database in my solution in visual studio 2010]

I have several windows forms in my solution (log-in form, main window form, and search form). When a user logs in, the main window form appears and the log-in form hides [data from the log-in form is then passed to the main window form that will be used to access the database in other functions - sorry for not putting this small detail before]. when a user presses a button in the main window form to search the database, a new form (search form) appears. In the search form the user can search for data in the database and select the data from the database.

problem:

when the user wants to select some data from the database, I get stuck on how the current form (search form) will pass the data to the main window form.

Any help in this is very appreciated. And to make things clear to everyone, this is not in any form of a homework.

^_^

Comment: what do u want to pass to main form...??

Comment: u r passing single value or multiple values, to main form..???

Comment: I hope this link will helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7886544/passing-a-value-from-one-form-to-another-form

Comment: i want to pass an ID (single value)from the search from (the primary key in a row after the user loads data to the the form) back to the main form.

Comment: @pratapk - that thread does provide a few solutions but only the answers by [Veldmuis](http://stackoverflow.com/users/18826/veldmuis) and [Marco](http://stackoverflow.com/users/604015/marco) look object-oriented.  The c-sharpcorner article mentioned by [TGH](http://stackoverflow.com/users/336423/tgh) (see answer) suggests 4 solutions but none is object-oriented. Of course you might not need/want an object-oriented solution but FWIW the other solutions break the rule of encapsulation. Encapsulation means that `Form2` should know nothing about `Form1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either add a property or a method on the MainForm that you can call on the instance representing your MainForms

In SearchForm:

```
mainForm.SomeMethod(..) or mainFor.SomeProperty = val
```

Or... you can create a delegate property on the search from that points to a method in your MainForm. The delegate would be assigned to the SearchForm when it's created.

Comment: haven't touched delegate property before. Thanks for the tip. I'll try it out and post what happens.

Comment: how exactly do i create a delegate property and point it to a method in my main form?

Comment: Take a look at this article. It talks about various ways to do what you're trying to do (including delegates) http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/thiagu304/passdata05172006234318PM/passdata.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the article. Will try the approaches out.