# Form2 Value returns 0 when exit

Tags: c#, winforms

I have MAIN FORM and FORM 2 (which is a modal form).

When I enter FORM 2, there is a combo box and the selected value will be stored in a class. From there, it works fine because the messagebox confirms that the value is stored.

But when I exit FORM 2 and back to MAIN FORM to display that value in a textbox, the value now returns 0.

FORM 2:

```
private void btnOK_BS__Spec_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BSIT bsit = new BSIT();
    string spec = cboIT_Spec.Text;

    do
    {
        if (spec == "Animation and Game Development" || spec == "Digital Arts")
        {
            bsit.setSpec(spec);
            MessageBox.Show("You chose " + bsit.getSpec() + ".", "Specialization",
            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);     
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please select your Specialization.");
        }
    }
    while (bsit.getSpec() == "");
}
```

CLASS

```
public class BSIT : Student
{
    public BSIT()
    {
        spec = "";
    }

    private string spec;

    public void setSpec(string spec)
    {
        if (spec == "Animation and Game Development" || spec == "Digital Arts")
        {
            this.spec = spec;
        }
    }

    public string getSpec()
    {
        return spec;
    }
}
```

MAIN FORM (Display the value of spec)

```
private void txbxSpec_Input_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BSIT bsit = new BSIT();

    if (!(bsit.getSpec() == ""))
    {
        txbxSpec_Input.Text = bsit.getSpec();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You've got two separate instances of your `BSIT` class. You need to pass the first instance into your instance of FORM 2 or make the BSIT class static.

At least I think that's the cause, from what I can see in the code you posted. I don't see where you're instantiating the form that contains your `btnOK_BS__Spec_Click` event.

You're "new"ing up an instance of `BSIT` in the `btnOK_BS__Spec_Click` event and saving your value to it, but it goes out of scope as soon as the event ends so you lose your value. Then you're trying to get the user's value from the first instance of `BSIT`.

Answer (score 0):

you should send init new instace of you BSIT in Main form and then pass it to Form2 so two form access to a sinle instance , somthing like this :

here i define a constructor form Form2 to give BSIT instance form form main

```
Public class Form2
{
  BSIT result;
  public Form2(BSIT bsit)
  {
     result = bist;
  }

  ...
}
```

now when you init form2 in mainform you should have somthing like this :

```
BIST resultFromForm2 = new BIST();
Form2 frm = new Form2(resultFromForm2);
frm.showDialog();
```

and you should have somthing like thid in you button click event handler :
(as you can see i change the "result" which we set it in constructor before)

```
private void btnOK_BS__Spec_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string spec = cboIT_Spec.Text;

    do
    {
        if (spec == "Animation and Game Development" || spec == "Digital Arts")
        {
            result.setSpec(spec);
            MessageBox.Show("You chose " + result.getSpec() + ".", "Specialization",
            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);     
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please select your Specialization.");
        }
    }
    while (result.getSpec() == "");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hi you can refer the below links ..

[Passing a value from one form to another form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7886544/passing-a-value-from-one-form-to-another-form/15967973#15967973)

or

http://csharpprobsandsoln.blogspot.in/2013/04/passing-value-from-one-form-to-other.html