# Pass windows form instance as parameter

Tags: c#, winforms

I have windows form which is calling another class's method and need to be passed as parameter.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {                
        private myClass _myClass;       

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _myClass = new myClass(//pass this instance - Form1 - as parameter)
        }
    }
```

But I don't know how to pass Form1 instance as parameter? I need to do this, because this other class is creating system tray icon and menu strip and is able to close the parent form.

Comment: Using `Parameterized constructor` you can pass an arguments

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing a value from one form to another form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7886544/passing-a-value-from-one-form-to-another-form)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'd just do:

```
_myClass = new myClass(this);
```

And then change the constructor in myClass:

```
public class myClass
{
    private Form1 theForm;

    public myClass(Form1 theForm)
    {
        this.theForm = theForm;
    }

    ...
}
```

Now you can access the form from within the class. I think I'd avoid doing this though. Try to leave the form in charge of calling the class and determining when it should close itself.

Having the class hold a reference back to the form that instantiated it, and closing it from within the class seems like it could lead to confusion and maintainability issues down the road.

Comment: So you're suggesting that I don't pass form as parameter to the class? At first I wanted to pass my form as reference parameter.

Comment: This class is system tray - it should open and close form when pressing buttons. I guess with opening or closing form I don't do any modifications to the form itself. That is why I need reference.

Answer (score 3):

Simply declare a parameter of type `Form` in the other's class constructor:

```
public class myClass
{
    private Form otherForm;

    public myClass(Form form) 
    {
        otherForm = form;
    }
}
```

and call it from within `Form1`:

```
_myClass = new myClass(this);
```

Answer (score 2):

I can't figure out what you want to achieve. but if you just want to pass this form than you can use this.

```
_myClass = new myClass(this);
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can:

```
_myClass = new myClass(this);
```

Comment: we cant actually as it contains read only properties and generates syntax error in c#

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, this ought to be fairly straightforward:

```
    public Form1(myClass instance)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _myClass = instance;
    }
```