# Method return value resets value after changing into another form

Tags: c#, forms

I have a form, Form2 which contains a Hangman game (yes, it is the similar Hangman game to the one that i'm referring to in my previous question) and once the player finishes the game, the player will be brought to either one of two forms, Form4 and Form6 (one is a congratulations form for winning and one is a mocking/defeat form for losing) and in both forms Form4 and Form6, there is a label that displays the score that the player gets from the previous Form2.

I had placed a method to return the value of the score in Form2.

```
public int getScore()
{
    return score;
}
```

And then in both forms, Form4 and Form6, there is these codes in each form respectively.

Form4

```
private void Form4_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 game = new Form2();
    lblFinalScore.Text += game.getScore().ToString(); 
}
```

Form6

```
private void Form6_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 game = new Form2();
    lblFinalScore.Text += game.getScore().ToString(); 
}
```

So after passing Form2 and playing the game, and when for example, I won the game and got 7 points, and Form4 appears, the lblFinalScore displays 0... WHY?!
Please help...

Comment: Because you are creating two different instances of `Form2`.

Comment: @RohitVats Then what am i supposed to do?

Comment: Pass actual `Form2` instance to other forms and use that instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the new keyword you create a new instance of the Form2 class.
This way you are using two different instances. Differnt instances are having data fields with different values.

If you want to access the same data field from any intances of a class, use the static keyword. You could store the score value in a static field, this way you could easily access it.

If you have a static field defined in a class, you can access the very field from any instance. However, using static fields are highly discouraged, since this violates basic OO principles.

Example:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ExampleClass ex1 = new ExampleClass();
            ExampleClass ex2 = new ExampleClass();

            ex1.normalfield = "new value for ex1";
            ex2.normalfield = "new value for ex2";
            ExampleClass.staticfield = "static value";

            Console.WriteLine(ex1.normalfield);
            Console.WriteLine(ex2.normalfield);
            Console.WriteLine(ExampleClass.staticfield);

        }

        class ExampleClass
        {
            public string normalfield = "";
            public static string staticfield = "";
        }
```

}

Passing the original instance of the Form could be a better way to go in your situation.
This could be done by storing a reference to the Form, or implementing the Singleton pattern.

However, the best solution in my opinion, would be to decouple the presentation of your game logic. You should be using a different class to implement the game logic and to store data values connected to the game and the form classes should be only responsible to present visually the current state of the object representing the state of your game.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating *two different instances* of `Form2`. Refer to actual original instance of Form2.

Have class level variable on both `Form4` and `Form6` and set it from respective constructor. Pass instance from Form2.

Refer to [Passing a value from one form to another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7886667/632337).