# Passing values from one form to another form

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

I have two forms named Form1 and Form2:

Form1 is a list of some values that are inserted on a table in SQL
Form2 is a validation of the values that are inserted on the table.

When I click the Form1 button, this will show up Form2 and Insert the values in the table, also Any inputs in textBox in Form 1 should be written back to Form2 TextBoxes.

I have the code below but it doesn't work.

```
////Form1 Code
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 F2= new Form2();
        F2.Show();
        this.Hide();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MXPEDAMAP401;Initial Catalog=VentaCajas;User ID=sa;Password=1TservicesMX");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand("insert into DatosGenerales values('" + textBox2.Text + "','" + textBox3.Text + "','" + textBox4.Text + "','"+ textBox1.Text + "','" + listBox1.Text + "','" + textBox5.Text + "','" + listBox2.Text + "', getdate());",con);
        int o=sc.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Verifica que los datos esten correctos");
        con.Close();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: esta línea de código carga datos en la tabla 'ventaCajasDataSet1.LugarEntrega' Puede moverla o quitarla según sea necesario.
        this.lugarEntregaTableAdapter.Fill(this.ventaCajasDataSet1.LugarEntrega);
        // TODO: esta línea de código carga datos en la tabla 'ventaCajasDataSet.TipoContrato' Puede moverla o quitarla según sea necesario.
        this.tipoContratoTableAdapter.Fill(this.ventaCajasDataSet.TipoContrato);

    }
}
}



////Form2 Code
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MXPEDAMAP401;Initial Catalog=VentaCajas;User ID=sa;Password=1TservicesMX");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand("delete DatosGenerales where No_Empleado+Tipo_Contrato = '';('" + textBox4.Text + "," + textBox5.Text + "');", con);
        int o = sc.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Form1 F1 = new Form1();
        F1.Show();
        this.Close();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("¡Gracias!");
        this.Close();
    }
}
}
```

Some Screenshots :

[image][image]

How can I realize that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing a value from one form to another form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7886544/passing-a-value-from-one-form-to-another-form)

Comment: Sounds like its the same, but it's different in the quantity of values that have to be moved from one to other page.

Comment: The "quantity of values" doesn't make the question a different question per se. You need to explain in more detail why this question is not addressed by that one, nor the [literally hundreds if not thousands of other similar questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?page=1&tab=newest&q=%5bc%23%5d%20pass%20value%20form%20to%20form) already on Stack Overflow. Moving data from one object to another is a basic C# concept, and has been addressed many times before already.

Comment: Can you please make sure that you correctly close your SQL connections and SQL commands. Research the `using` command.

Answer (score 1):

You can just pass values through the constructor as you've always done with any classes in C#.

Otherwise, for the reverse way, in `Form2` have an instance property. Set that property inside the `Form2` code. Before you destroy the form, read it from `Form1`.

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public int MyValue { get; set; }

    public Form2()
    {

        // somwhere in this code:
        MyValue = 3;
```

And then:

```
Form2 F2= new Form2();
F2.Show();
// ...

int myValue = F2.MyValue; // form 1 can just read the value of form 2 (which is "3")
```