# Items Count of listbox on another form

Tags: c#, listbox

While I'm debugging, the value of `ex` always comes back as 0.

I can't modify or read `ListBox` values on different form. I have two forms here.
How can I resolve this?

```
Form1 eski = new Form1();
Form2 yeni = new Form2();

ListBox array = new ListBox();
int ex = eski.listBox5.Items.Count;
for (int ix = 0; ix <= ex; ix++)
{
    array.Items.Add(eski.listBox5.Items[ix]);
}
```

Comment: If `ex` is zero, that's because `eski.listBox5.Items.Count` is zero, and that's because `listBox5` on `Form1` is empty. Where do you populate it? It would have to be design time or in the Form1 constructor for this code to work.

Comment: There are 6 items in eski.listbox5 i dont understand you exactly

Comment: How do the 6 items get there?

Comment: listbox5.Items.Add(latt1) with this code on Form1 
latt 1 is a double

Comment: Where is that code in Form1?

Comment: listBox5.Items.Add(latt1);
                listBox6.Items.Add(lonn1);
                listBox7.Items.Add(uzaklik);

Comment: No, which function in Form1?

Comment: https://i.hizliresim.com/5GpMp5.jpg

You can see the part which i added items to listbox5 on  Form1

Comment: That's in a button click handler. You are doing `Form1 eski = new Form1();`, and then immediately looking at the list. You don't even show the form, let alone click a button on it.

Comment: I think your confusion is coming from the use of `Form1 eski = new Form1();`. You can't do that if you want to refer to an existing, visible, `Form1` instance. You need to pass `eski` and `yeni` into the code in your question, instead of creating them there.

Comment: Should i add eski.show(); ?

Comment: I don't think so. In which form is the code you put in your question?

Comment: How can i create that passing between eski and yeni?

Comment: Code in my question is on form2.cs

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7886544/passing-a-value-from-one-form-to-another-form

Comment: I saw this but there is only label and textbox there , but i have two listbox how can i apply that for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem on your code is this one:

```
Form1 eski = new Form1();
```

You are initializing a new form and this code will not call the `opened Form1` which is already running on your application.

You need to replace that and do this instead:

```
var eski = Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form1>().SingleOrDefault();
```

With that, you can now access the controls that you want.

Comment: Okay, if this answers your question, you can accept it as reference to others. Thanks! @Onurİn

Comment: Thats great it works :) Thanks a lot that was so important for me :)
So sometimes i have questions like this im new developer i cant handle everything easily .. Can you help me from here when you saw my question :)